# How to monitor some websites continuously and perform actions regularly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

What I want to do is to post my question on a forum (e.g. Stack Overflow) and have a program concentrate on it. When someone have post their answer or reply on my post, then the program will send me an email to inform me.

One way that I could think of is to perform it using PHP with `file_get_contents` or `curl`. Keep fetching the content of the website regularly, when the number of posts / reply is changed, then send an email to me. I know that way is quite stupid so I would like to know if there are any other ways to do it.

I prefer using PHP, but if there are any other programming language which can achieve that goal are also welcome.

Comment: Scraping the site may be the best you can do in some cases. However, you should prefer an API if the site offers one, and failing that, see if an RSS feed is offered. If you wanted to keep an eye on Stack Overflow, RSS would be a great way to do it. However, make sure you respect "robots.txt", and ensure you apply a decent rate limit, otherwise you can expect to be blocked at the IP level.

Comment: [It's been done](http://stackapps.com/), there's a site for it called stackapps

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem he was just using it as an example.

Comment: Thank you for replying me so quick. Actually StackOverFlow is just an example for explaining my question, I would like to perform it on other forums. However, as far as I know, there are no that kind of APIs provide by those forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the given website has an API, you can use it and create a PHP script that would fetch the required content of the given site. If it doesn't have an API, you can simply [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) the URL and check if there are changes. Directly scraping the website is generally regarded as a bad idea and hence I don't recommend it.

Once you have the script up and running, you can schedule it as a cronjob and have the script run at regular time intervals.

As for sending emails, you can use PHPMailer of SwiftMailer -- both are excellent tools to send emails from within a PHP script.